# Different behavior of read from binary file

Tags: python, bufferedreader

I would like to read a binary file in blocks of 128-bytes.

I tried to achieve this with:

```
 with open('someFile.bin', "rb") as file:
     for block in file.read(128): 
            print(block)
```

As a result I get only one byte per block, but I get 128 blocks.
If I do:

```
with open('someFile.bin', "rb") as file:
   block = file.read(128)
   print(block)
```

The result is as expected, block is a binary string with 128 bytes.

Why does the read-method behave differently in these two situations and how could I achieve my goal to read the complete file in blocks of n-bytes?

Comment: It should be pretty clear why `x = y` is different from `for x in y`, no?

Comment: for clarification: `read(n)` returns either a string or in your case a bytes-object of length `n` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)) - both are iterables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file.read(n)` returns an iterable with `n` bytes. Iterating through it using a for loop as in the first case will result in `block` holding only one byte at a time.

In the second case, you're printing the whole iterable, i.e. all the `n` bytes read.

Comment: In the documentation it was not clear, that an iterable is returned. I thought file.read(n) will yield a byte-string with the specified number of bytes.

Comment: In python, strings (or byte-strings for that matter) **are** iterables. In that regard, a string is essentially an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over a file, you can basicly use file.read(128). This command gives the next 128 bytes if used again.